# Find "a" tag using pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have to select last "a" tag. Remember that "ul" is optional, sometime it will generate or sometime not.
    How may I acheive it using "last-child" pseudo class.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span>Your location ：</span>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <ul class="list-item">
        <li>
            <a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use **ul li a:last-child{ css configuration here }** and **a:last-child{ css configuration here }**

Comment: if your `<a>` tags are held within different parent elements it means that CSS engine should work across different parents => impossible

Answer (score 1):

```
.breadcrumbs > a:last-child, .breadcrumbs ul > li:last-child a
{
}
```

So, if `a` is the last child of a `.breadcrumbs`, in the case there is no `ul` (nor any other element following that last `a`),

or if there is an `ul`, then the `a` of that `ul`'s last `li`.

Comment: If there's an <a> tag after the <ul> then this code will select the last <li> child inside <ul> as well as the last <a> after the <ul>. So you will end up with 2 <a> tags being selected. Test code: ...                                                               
                   <li>
                        <a href="#">4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#">5</a>
            </div>

Answer (score 1):

try pseudo selector `:nth-of-type` it'll select last-child of anchor

```css
.breadcrumbs *:last-of-type:not(a) *:last-of-type a{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <span>Your location ：</span>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <ul class="list-item">
        <li>
            <a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: With Chrome, links 2,3 and 4 have background color #ccc